# Thymleaf form submission results in 404?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a form in Thymeleaf I have written that takes data from the user. It looks like this:

```html
  <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/addArticle}" th:object="${article}" method="post">
     <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{title}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{authors}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{genre}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{date}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
```

The problem is, whenever I submit this form, it does not save to the mongo database or even display a results page. Instead, it throws a 404. I notice that this error comes from the url:

> http://localhost:8080/addArticle

This is strange, because I'm trying to redirect to a page I have called return.html (it exists in the correct directory and I have tested that the html is valid). This is my controller:

```
>@Controller
@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class ArticleController {

    private ArticleRepo articleRepo;

    @Autowired
    public ArticleController(ArticleRepo articleRepo) {
        this.articleRepo = articleRepo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Article> findall() {
        return articleRepo.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/addArticle")
    public String getAddArticle(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("article", new Article());
        return "submitAnArticle";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addArticle")
    public String submitAddArticle(@ModelAttribute Article newArticle) {
        articleRepo.save(newArticle);
        return "result";
    }


}
```

I've tried browsing stack overflow and using [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) Spring documentation for reference, but I'm stuck. I have a few questions about this:

**Most Important Question**
1. Can anyone get this form working or possibly can identify this error?

*Bonus Questions*
2. I already had this successfully working in Javascript before I switched to Thymeleaf's weird form stuff. Is there anyway I can just take the data from here and put it into javascript like I used to? I tried using standard html form stuff, but it doesn't do anything.
3. Is there a way this can be done without redirecting the page via AJAX?

It seems that I'm stumping stack overflow with my questions because they're consistently upvoted, but either have incorrect responses or none at all. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"Can anyone get this form working "_ -- not unless you provided the entire application.  That is not going to happen, and this question is off-topic as too broad.  If you can provide an [mcve] that demonstrates the issue then maybe we can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based upon your code sample It will sure throw 404 error. In your controller your are mapping twice in

```
@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class ArticleController
```

and

```
@PostMapping("/addArticle")
public String submitAddArticle(@ModelAttribute Article newArticle) {
```

so your url will be

```
http://localhost:8080/articles/addArticle
```

but you are trying to post in

```
http://localhost:8080/addArticle
```

Comment: ...So how do you fix this?

Comment: Try this. In your form change `th:action="@{/addArticle}"` to `th:action="@{/articles/addArticle}"` or remove `@RequestMapping("/articles")` from the controller.

Answer (score 2):

looking at the mapping, isn't your URL http://localhost:8080/articles/addArticle ?, try removing the "/" from the action :

`th:action="@{addArticle}"`

otherwise this might cause the url to be taking from the root i.e. :

```
http://localhost:8080/addArticle
```

**EDIT:** Also, you stated that:

> because I'm trying to redirect to a page I have called return.html

but in your controller you are returning `result`, try changing it to :

```
@PostMapping("/addArticle")
public String submitAddArticle(@ModelAttribute Article newArticle) {
    articleRepo.save(newArticle);
    return "return";
}
```

Comment: This definitely takes me to the correct URL, but it still says 404.

I have noticed that Thymeleaf throws 404s pretty frequently even whenever the error isn't truly a 404. For example, if the html for a page isn't formatted so that it's recognizable to Thymeleaf, it'll just throw a 404 but show the line in question within the document.

Comment: That was a typo on my part. I'm trying to return "result" and it's not doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not import necessary jar, put  these in pom.xml or download by yourself

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```